# What can cause the Hessian to lose positive semi-definiteness in Newton's method

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods, positive-semidefinite

I have been looking at some code for Newton's method. My sources (Nocedal and Wright), indicate that Newton's method works very well in many cases, but that often the method can fail because the Hessian can lose positive semidefiniteness.

I was trying to graphically understand what happens when a Hessian loses positive semidefiniteness in an optimization problem. I understand the definition of positive semidefiniteness (non-negative eigenvalues), but I am not sure what is the mechanism by which the Hessian loses this property, and what the corresponding effect on the optimization trajectory is.

Comment: For a 1D problem, the Hessian is just $f''(x)$. Try imagining a case when you would have $f''(x)<0$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt so in the 1d case, $f''(x)$ would just mean the curve is concave down, so it has a maximum instead of a minimum. The critical points are a property of the function itself, as opposed to Newton's method. In the multidimensional case, I suppose positive semidefiniteness means you hit some saddle points. So does Newton's method stall at such saddle points? Then would methods like BFGS approximate a positive definite matrix at the saddle point and then continue the optimization, whereas Newton's method probably has the stepsize collapse to really small steps.

Comment: Newton's method comverges to saddle points, such as with $f(x)=x^3$. Methods like BFGS can do the same, but what you'll usually do is force it to be positive semi-definite e.g. by trust regions.

Comment: It can be proven, that if the Hessian is positive definite, then the Newton's direction is descent. Proof: if $\bf{H}$ is pos.def. then also $\bf{H}^{-1}$ is pos. def. Then use $\bf{x}^{\text{T}}\bf{H}^{-1}\bf{x} \ge 0$ for $\bf{x}=-\bf{g}$, where $\bf{g}$ is gradient, then you get  $[-\bf{g}]^{\text{T}}[-\bf{H}^{-1}\bf{g}] \ge 0$ $\diamondsuit$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Yeah, that makes sense. I am still not clear on how BFGS gets past the saddle point, instead of getting stuck circling around the saddle? The trust region will shrink the step length to find a length that does reduce the function more than some threshold. So I guess BFGS will take really small steps around the saddle but on the other side of the saddle the minimization continues. Is that the right way to think about it, or am I missing something